# Create data to be outputted in a view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my view I output data from my database in the view via:

```
{{ $data->id }}
```

In one particular view I need do not get the data from a database but need to keep the view the same and manually set the id.

I've tried setting the id in my controller like:

```
$data['id'=>1];
```

But this fails to output in the view with:

```
{{ $data->id }}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: so just do {{$id}} and give the view the id

Comment: You can try `$data = ['id'=>1]` or `$data[$id] = 1` instead of `$data['id'=>1]`

Answer (score 0):

You would want:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->id = 1;
```

Creating something like that will create an object (like an array, but accessed with `$data->id` instead of `$data['id']`.

To make your code simpler, Laravel has magic getters which means you can use `$data['id']` in your view for data from the database.  Then, when not using the database, you could do `$data['id'] = 1;` in your code rather than the two lines above.